# FQL facebook query about friends events

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I have a question about FQL query:

This query:

```
SELECT pic_big, name, venue, location, start_time, eid 
FROM event
WHERE eid IN (
    SELECT eid
    FROM event_member
    WHERE uid IN (
        SELECT uid2
        FROM friend
        WHERE uid1 = me()
    ) 
    AND start_time > '2013-02-21T00:00:00'
    OR uid = me()
)
```

is equivalent to requiring the events of every my friend?

```
for each friend {

    SELECT name, description, pic_small, pic_big, eid,venue, location 
    FROM event
    WHERE eid in (
        SELECT eid 
        FROM event_member
        WHERE uid = me()
        AND start_time > '2013-02-21T00:00:00'
    )

}
```

I have different results..In the SECOND way (I have also excluded my events  uid = me ())I obtained many more events...

Comment: Care to provide the actual content of the '...' in your second query, just so we can check you're not screwing something up there? Anyway, a possible explanation might be that you're hitting the roughly 5000 row result limit for most FQL queries; are you getting just under 5000 results doing things the first way?

Comment: @Mark Amery I edited my post. In both cases I did not reach the limit of never results (more than 5000)